# Integration with Heaviside function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've some problems with Mathematica when it comes to integrate heaviside functions.

I have to integrate the following function:

$$f(x,z) = -12*(1+x-z)*(x-z+\rho)*\Theta(-(x^2-x*z+\rho))*\Theta(z^2/4-(\rho))*\Theta(1+\rho-z)$$ with the Assumption:
 $$0 < \rho <1, x  real, z  real $$.

I want to integrate first over x and then over z. The result should be:

$$ 1 - 8*(\rho) + 8*(\rho)^3 - (\rho)^4 -12*(\rho)^2 Log[\rho] $$

Unfortunately, Mathematica cannot handle the Heaviside function and outputs me that the integral does not converge in the limits

```
{x,-Infinity,Infinity}, {z,-Infinity,Infinity}
```

.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: The code rho = 2/3; NIntegrate[-12*(1 + x - z)*(x - z + rho)*
  Piecewise[{{1, -(x^2 - x*z + rho) >= 0}, {0, -(x^2 - x*z + rho) < 
      0}}]*Piecewise[{{1, z^2/4 - rho >= 0}, {0, z^2/4 - rho < 0}}]*
  Piecewise[{{1, 1 + rho - z >= 0}, {0, 1 + rho - z < 0}}], {x, -100, 
  100}, {z, -100, 200}] outputs $-1.03332\times 10^8 $, confirming the divergence.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful